# sliderInput to appear in side-bar only when a Tab is selected

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a Shinyapp in line of below template :

```
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              menuItem("Tab1", tabName="Tab1", selected=TRUE),
              menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2")
  ),

  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='Tab1'",
                   fluidRow()
                   ),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='Tab2'",
                   fluidRow()
                   )
  )


body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(

    tabItem(tabName = "Tab1",
            fluidRow( sliderInput("aa", "aa", value = 0.9, min = 0, max = 2, step=0.1))
    ),
     tabItem(tabName = "Tab2",
           fluidRow(navbarPage(id = 'ab', title = "", 
                        tabPanel(title = "aa1", value = 'aa1', fluidRow()),
                        tabPanel(title = "aa2", value = 'aa2', fluidRow())))
    )))


ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My tab"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server = function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now what I want basically, a sliderInput should appear in the Side panel only when `TabPanel = 'aa2'` from `tabItem = 'Tab2'`. Therefore user should not see that sliderInput if `TabPanel = 'aa1'` is selected.

So far I have tried something like below :

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              menuItem("Tab1", tabName="Tab1", selected=TRUE),
              menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2")
  ),

  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='Tab1'",
                   fluidRow()
                   ),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='Tab2'",
                   fluidRow(sliderInput("aa5", "aa", value = 0.9, min = 0, max = 2, step=0.1))
                   )
  )
```

However with this the sliderInput is visible for both `tabPanel = "aa1"` & `tabPanel = "aa2"`, which I do not want.

Any suggestion, how can I make sliderInput is visible only for `tabPanel = "aa2"`.

Thanks for your pointer.

Comment: You could try using `hide` function from `shinyjs` package. This would be done from the server side. You can follow [this](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/overview#demo) link.

Answer (score 2):

@SBista thanks for pointer. Below is updated code. Thanks,

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              menuItem("Tab1", tabName="Tab1", selected=TRUE),
              menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2")
  ),

  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='Tab1'",
                   fluidRow()
                   ),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='Tab2'",
                   fluidRow(useShinyjs(),
                    column(12, sliderInput("aa4", "aa", value = 0.9, min = 0, max = 2, step=0.1)))
                   )
  )


body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(

    tabItem(tabName = "Tab1",
            fluidRow( sliderInput("aa", "aa", value = 0.9, min = 0, max = 2, step=0.1))
    ),
     tabItem(tabName = "Tab2",
           fluidRow(navbarPage(id = 'ab', title = "", 
                        tabPanel(title = "aa1", value = 'aa1', fluidRow()),
                        tabPanel(title = "aa2", value = 'aa2', fluidRow())))
    )))


ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My tab"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server = function(input, output) {

observe(toggle(id = "aa4", condition = ifelse(input$ab == 'aa2', TRUE, FALSE)))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```